# Multiple Internet Explorer instances on one machine

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463)

I am looking for a tool that can allow me to run Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7 (and Internet Explorer 8 if possible) on my machine. I found something on the Internet like [this](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) and some other interesting solutions, but I need your opinion based on experience. Which is the best choice for running multiple Internet Explorer instances from the point of view of a web-developer?

---

Edit: thank you for the help, I installed some of the tools you suggested, and I decided to stick to those two: [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) and [IE Collection](http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm) - easy to install, intuitive UI and fast response time.

The others:

- [xenocode](http://www.xenocode.com/Browsers/) just crashed or I
     couldn't install it properly.
- [Multiple IE](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/8/568F0D28-0434-4794-B7FC-FB293BCC98FB/SuperPreview%5FTrial%5Fen.exe) wanted me to
     install Microsoft .NET which took
     eternity and at the end,
     surprise...nothing worked. Then
     again it's probably my poor
     installing skills
- [IE Application
     Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) seems to
     be the most professional approach to
     the issue but I just liked IETester
     and IE Collection better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used this:

http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE

This will get IE 6 going and earlier versions if that's a priority.  Then you can just install IE 8 because it allows you to use IE7 "compatibility mode" so you can effectively mimic IE7.

Comment: A word of warning: IE7 Compat and IE7 Real are subtly different (google for it).

Comment: Afair that one does not work on Vista.

Answer (score 11):

Microsoft provides VPC virtual hard drives with various OS images and IE versions for just this purpose:

- [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en)

Note that the OS installs are time-bombed so you have to periodically download new images from MS.

Comment: You also need VPC itself, which is here:  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=28C97D22-6EB8-4A09-A7F7-F6C7A1F000B5&displaylang=en

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Windows you can try the new SuperPreview tool: http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/6/8/568F0D28-0434-4794-B7FC-FB293BCC98FB/SuperPreview_Trial_en.exe

Comment: Doesn't run any javascript though.  Kind of useless for testing AJAX functionality...

Answer (score 2):

You can install multiple versions of IE using this installer: http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). It's "for free" and follow its updates.

Answer (score -1):

I've had fairly good results using [Xenocode](http://www.xenocode.com/Browsers/) for browser testing

Comment: Can you supply a bit more information on how Xenocode works. Mozilla just crashes when I try to run it. ty.