# How to view webpages with different browser versions in firefox and chrome?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, browser

In the latest version of internet explorer if you press <kbd>F12</kbd> you can bring up a menu that allows you to view the webpage with a different version of IE.[image]

Is there an equivalent functionality for this in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: That doesn't allow you to actually view the site in different IE versions.  It allows you to view the site in different modes of IE9 that mostly work like the older IE versions... but not quite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, theres no such function (in firefox at least, im not 100% sure about chrome), but maybe something like [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/) helps you out.

on it you can post an url and the site makes screenshots in a lot of different browsers, so you can see layout problems (but note that you cant test functionality this way).

Answer (score 4):

Simply install different Firefox versions, choosing a different installation directory is sufficient. You can run them in parallel if you specify the [`-no-remote` command line option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Command_Line_Options#-no-remote). In that case you need at least two [browser profiles](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing-profiles) however.

As to Chrome, versions older than the current release are generally not supported - in theory nobody should be running them. Chrome also has [very limited support for using multiple browser versions in parallel](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel). If you want to have the beta/dev version in addition to the stable version then [Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) should be your best option.

**Edit**: Actually, I tried using Google Chrome Portable and it is everything but a perfect solution - updates don't work so you will have to reinstall it regularly even if the portable builds keep up with Google's release pace. In the end [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785991/can-i-run-multiple-versions-of-google-chrome-on-the-same-machine-mac-or-windows/3786165#3786165) seems to be the best solution - Chrome installs in the user account so you can create additional accounts for other Chrome versions. Windows allows switching to these accounts without shutting down your session so it isn't quite as bad as it sounds.