# How to isolate an older version of chrome on linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, isolation

I need to run chrome 25 on my ubuntu saucy for testing of a web application. I don't want to replace my current version of chrome and was wondering if there is a simple way to isolate a program? I have ubuntu running in a chroot on my Chromebook pixel so nothing that requires kvm.

Comment: Can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785991/can-i-run-multiple-versions-of-google-chrome-on-the-same-machine-mac-or-window ?  It might be a solution (and your question a dupe...)

Comment: Thats a beautiful answer, that I saw before posting my question, if i was working on windows not linux.

Comment: afaik the general setup should be the same under Windows and Linux, just not the names of directories - look here as well http://superuser.com/questions/353528/running-multiple-versions-of-chrome