# Do I have to install chrome on node machine before configuring node with chrome browser

Tags: json, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am trying to implement selenium Grid with Hub and Nodes using JSON files.I have the following questions.

1. On the node machine, where is the browser getting installed.
2. If I am using my Windows machine as node, and I don't have chrome browser installed on my machine, would I still be able to configure the same machine as node with Chrome Browser.
3. What is the version relevance in .json file for node

   "capabilities":
     [
       {
         "browserName": "chrome",
         "version": "40.0.2214.115",
         "maxInstances": 1
       }

   ],

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are not clear, may be it's caused by missing '?'.

Anyway. You need Chrome Browser to be installed on node. Node could be started without it but would not be usable. You can download standalone version if your machine in internal network and has no connection to Internet.

For version parameter you may use only 2 symbols, '40' in your case. Refer to Chrome Driver release notes - [ChromeDriver v2.14 (2015-01-28)](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.14/notes.txt) to get supported versions.

Comment: Thank you.  My 3rd question was like if I have chrome version 40 installed on the machine and in nodeconfig.json if I mention as capabilities": [ { "browserName": "chrome", "version": "39", "maxInstances": 1 },    will this work

Comment: As for me I don't specify version of chrome browser because have no need to test backward compatibility. I have node with latest chrome driver and chrome browser v41 and configured node with chrome version 42 and all works fine (as I see, but I suppose that v41 is used). But I'm sure that if you want to test with different version of chrome you should have separate chrome driver and chrome browser for each version/node (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10917231/2046571))