# Is it possible to install different chrome versions on a windows machine?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I need to check a website on different chrome versions and I am trying to do it on the same machine. I don't know if this is still possible now or not. I know it was before from older questions such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785991/can-i-run-multiple-versions-of-google-chrome-on-the-same-machine-mac-or-window).

So my questions if it is possible how to install different version of chrome on the same computer ?

Comment: Just curious, but why - given that Chrome auto updates - do you have to test your site on different versions?

Comment: At some places auto update is bocked by firewall

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do is to use the unofficial !!  portable chrome version.
To bypasse this you can use **Browserling** extention to performe your browser compatibility tests.

Answer (score 1):

You could download an older version of Chromium from:

https://vikyd.github.io/download-chromium-history-version/

They can be installed alongside a regular Chrome.