# Run two different versions of chrome using selenium (Python)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I have a scenario to run different versions of chrome in windows (for now let us consider only two). I have found the following way to run an instance of chrome:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    chrome_options=chrome_options
)
```

I have default chrome and another version (located in Downloads directory). How do I run any desired version?

## EDIT:

I have some blogs written [here](https://e4example.blogspot.com/2017/07/run-different-version-of-firefox-using.html) and [here](https://e4example.blogspot.com/2017/07/run-different-version-of-chrome-using.html). Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Please refer this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785991/can-i-run-multiple-versions-of-google-chrome-on-the-same-machine-mac-or-window

Comment: It seems there's a `binary` option in the [ChromeOptions object](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-chromeOptions-object) that configures the path to a Chrome binary. Though this seems to be related to local Chrome instances only. This option seems to make no sense when running against a hub or remote standalone server since multiple version to path mappings should be configured _at the ChromeDriver side_ (that is passed to the _selenium server_) and the ChromeOptions should provide a `version` config (or alike) to instruct the server to choose the binary.

Comment: This one has step by step help https://e4example.blogspot.com/2017/07/run-different-version-of-chrome-using.html

Comment: BrowserStack of Sauce Labs are also options here - provide which browser versions you want through capabilities.

Comment: @alecxe Can you please provide me some links?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is to define the location in the capabilities with the `Options` class:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r'C:/chromium-48/chrome.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

or with `DesiredCapabilities`:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME;
capa['chromeOptions'] = {
  'binary': r'C:/chromium-48/chrome.exe',
  'args': []
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=capa)
```

But if you are looking for a scalable solution, then you should setup a grid with the different versions:

- Start the hub:

```bash
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -role hub -host 0.0.0.0 -port 4444
```

- Start a node for version 48:

```bash
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar 
 -role node 
 -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
 -browser platform=WINDOWS,browserName=chrome,version=48,chrome_binary="C:/chromium-48/chrome.exe"
```

- Start a node for version 54:

```bash
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar 
 -role node 
 -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
 -browser platform=WINDOWS,browserName=chrome,version=54,chrome_binary="C:/chromium-54/chrome.exe"
```

You can then choose the version directly in the capabilities:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
capa = {'browserName': 'chrome', 'version': '48', 'platform': 'ANY'}
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=capa)
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know soon. Thank you

Comment: Can you please give me the related link?

Comment: You want a link related to what?

Comment: Any relevant link. Is any tutorial/documentation present on web?

Comment: __options.binary_location = r'C:/chromium-48/chrome.exe'__ this one is enough for now. Will look at grid in future if needed. Thank you for the effort. :)

Comment: Use `Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium` for the binary path if your using a mac. (*.app is actually a folder on mac, the real binary is inside.)