# Python Selenium Chrome "user data directory is already in use"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-profile

I'm trying to make a script in python with selenium that will open a website and click a button.
Problem is that I have to close chrome before I can run the script otherwise I get this error:

```
Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

Is there a way around this so I don't have to close chrome before running the script everytime?

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://disboard.org/sv/dashboard/servers")

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("bump")
link.click()
```

Comment: As long as you are using your Chrome profile, you will have to close (some) Chrome browser . This could be either your default chrome browser or one you can make that is specific to web scraping. If you want to not close any browser, I would suggest using cookies instead of user data.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

...implies that the user data directory **Default** is already in use so [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to access the directory and initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

### Solution

In such cases, you can add/create a new [*Chrome Profile*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49270109/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-python/49280195#49280195) following the steps below and use it for the *AUT (Application Under Test)*:

- Open Google Chrome, and select the user icon in the top right and click on **Add**.

[image: Add New Chrome Profile]

- Enter a name for the new person, select an icon to help represent this new account and make it easier to find later. Then, select Add.

[image: Name_Shortcut_Done]

- You will find the [*Chrome Profile*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635087/how-to-open-a-chrome-profile-through-user-data-dir-argument-of-selenium/50637211#50637211) shortcut created on the *Desktop*.

[image: DesktopIcon]

- Additionally, you will find a new sub-directory *`Profile 1`* being created beside *`Default`*

[image: Profile1]

Now, you can use the *`Profile 1`* sub-directory as follows:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to use Chrome Profile in Selenium Webdriver Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52394408/how-to-use-chrome-profile-in-selenium-webdriver-python-3/52399027#52399027)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use error with real Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70385737/selenium-common-exceptions-invalidargumentexception-message-invalid-argument/70385974#70385974)
- [Selenium: Point towards default Chrome session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344560/selenium-point-towards-default-chrome-session/56401979#56401979)

Comment: A second profile does not solve the issue of the "user data" directory being used, because both profiles are in the same "user data" directory. What worked for me was copying the whole "user data" directory (as "user data selenium", for example) and then pointing to that new directory using the options.add_arguments method that you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your issue is because you have added the following argument:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
```

The argument is instructing selenium to use your local chrome profile. Hence, as you have a chrome session open, the automation cannot execute until you close down the browser session.

Remove the argument to execute an independent automation test profile.

See below for the remediated code provided from your question

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH, options=options)
driver.get("https://disboard.org/sv/dashboard/servers")

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("bump")
link.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is crucial for your use case that you can use both your Chrome profile and your automation with your profile at the same time, here's a possible solution:

1. Install a second (older or newer) version of Chrome as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785991/can-i-run-multiple-versions-of-google-chrome-on-the-same-machine-mac-or-window)
2. Enable synchronization on the desired profile in your current Chrome.
3. Log in with the desired profile from the second version of Chrome and enable synchronization there as well.
4. Use the chrome driver compatible with the second version of Chrome in your code.

There may be some problems with synchronization not loading everything that you need, but if it's something simple like saved passwords then this should work.