# selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use error with real Chrome Browser

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open website in my real Chrome not a driver But i got list of Errors and it does't open the url**
Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s = Service("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe")

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")
```

The Errors Like :

```
  C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Py Sele\Sele.py:11: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, chrome_options=options)
Opening in existing browser session.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Py Sele\Sele.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, chrome_options=options)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
    super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 93, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
```

Comment: "But i got list of Errors" can we see them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir
```

...implies that the `--user-data-dir` is already in use.

Your main issue is you have already an open *Google Chrome* browser session opened for your manual browsing.

There is no such error in your code block. However it seems you are executing program as an ***`Administrator`***. But,

> *A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. You need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.*

---

### Solution

Before you execute your test as an user e.g. *Administrator*, ensure that you don't have any open Chrome browser windows using the same user i.e. *Administrator*.

Comment: i forget that thank you.