# How to show object instance in Memory snapshot?

Tags: memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

I am following [this example](https://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art038) to learn more about Memory Snapshots.

The example mentions, that hoovering over an allocated object should show the object instance, e.g.
[image]

This would be super convenient, but it does not work for me.
[image]

Am I missing something, or is there some setting to activate this feature?

Notes:

- I am using Chrome Version `89.0.4389.82 64-bit` (also tried `91.0.4439.0`)
- Hoovering over variables in the `Sources` tab works
- I have already tried `Restore defaults and reload` in the `Settings` (still not working)
- A workaround for now is to right-click on the variable and select `Store as global variable`. Then we can see the object instance in the console.

Comment: https://crbug.com/1185573

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Chrome since version >= 88: [Issue 1185573: Hover preview for objects is broken in memory profiler](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1185573).
Thanks to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) for the comment

As a temporary workaround I have downloaded the **Portable Google Chrome Version 87** from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Google%20Chrome%20Portable).

Just exit all existing Chrome browser instances, install into a dedicated directory and run the executable named `GoogleChromePortable.exe`.
Actually this is perfect for testing, because we now also have a clean chrome user-profile without any installed extensions, etc.
And we can easily delete and reinstall the portable app.

See also: [Answer to "Can I run multiple versions of Google Chrome on the same machine? (Mac or Windows)"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12692156/1041641)