# Run multiple versions of Internet Explorer on Windows Vista

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer, multiple-versions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Multiple IE instances on one machine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693112/multiple-ie-instances-on-one-machine)
>   [Running IE6, IE7, and IE8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine)

This question might belong to the [Super User site](https://superuser.com/), but then again: this is about debugging HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Am I able to run Internet Explorer 5.5, 6.0, 7.0 and 8.0 on a single Windows Vista install? If yes: how?

**Update:** Duplicate of [this question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/693112/)

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693112/multiple-ie-instances-on-one-machine among many

Comment: Voted to close myself. Thanks for the tip Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser Compatibility Check for Internet Explorer Versions from 5.5 to 8:

[IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)

Comment: Seems solid. Thanks, CD.

Answer (score -1):

Don't install anything. Use Litmus: http://litmusapp.com/browser-testing

Comment: How would this work to show you how your animations/effects on your page look?