# Internet explorer 9 and internet explorer 10's browser mode, are they the same?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I've developed a javascript/ajax-intensive web app. There are no issues with FF and Chrome, and while testing on my IE 10 (using Browser Mode: IE9, Document Mode: IE9 Standards), the app also seems to be working fine in both IE10 and IE9.

But my boss, who has the *real* IE9 (not the IE10's IE9 browser mode version of it) is facing problems that I'm not facing. Jquery and ajax for him seem simply NOT to be working, working partially, or taking eons to load.

Is IE 10's browser mode not accurate? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you could provide some actual code or page to test?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it has some internal differences. Also take into account that IE has "Browser mode" and "Document mode" simulation. Some times combination of this two options may cause behavior which can't be reproduced in any _real_ IE version.

Answer (score 1):

Try some sort of emulator:

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

There are many more, also refer to:

[how to install multiple versions of IE on the same system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909459/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-ie-on-the-same-system)

Answer (score 1):

They should be the same however,

make sure that "his" browser is not switching to IE8 mode or compatibility mode. This happens a lot on intranets. Your can also try forcing the mode with X-UA-Compatible.

[Document Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Myself on our sites i set it as following to ensure that the user always uses the highest available version in standards mode: IE=11; IE=10; IE=9; IE8=8;

I set it with a custom header on our server (asp.NET)

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=11; IE=10; IE=9; IE8=8" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Or meta tags

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=11; IE=10; IE=9; IE8=8">
```

Also your doctype should be (without spaces before or above it! or IE will switch to quirks mode:: IE5.5 !) ..careful this happens a lot on asp and php sites, go to your site and display raw source to make sure.

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: so the meta tag will detect the IE version and ensure the user can view with the highest version, right? and no issues with FF/Chrome, of course.

Comment: The meta tag informs IE on which mode it should use on "this" particular site. Be sure to read the link i gave you "Document Compatibility", and the 5 links that complement the end of the section to properly understand whats going on here.