# Multiple Internet Explorer browsers

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463)

Is there any way to have Internet Explorer 6.0, Internet Explorer 7.0 and Internet Explorer 8.0 all installed on the same machine? Using Windows XP?

I am trying to test my web application, and it must be able to run in Internet Explorer 6-8.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine , others.

Comment: Visit http://modern.ie for free virtual machines to run IE on any platform you need. There are over 90 free virtual machines available covering all IE versions.

Answer (score 5):

Not that I know of ... we use [VirtualPC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en) to handle that situation.

Comment: http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/webdev.asp#vpc

Comment: Or [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)

Answer (score 5):

I think IETester is what you are looking for.
http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: works great as long as you don't have popups that interact with their opener... IETester doesn't handle those very well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a simple solution to this.  I think the best solutionis to setup something like VMWare and have multiple version of Windows installed on each:

- Windows XP - IE 6.x
- Windows XP - IE 7.x
- Windows XP - IE 8.x

I say Windows XP because you might have issues getting/installing older version of IE on Vista.

http://www.vmware.com/

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Start with IE 8 installed,

[Install IE7 Standalone](http://tredosoft.com/IE7_standalone)

[Install IE6 (and below if needed)](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE)

Answer (score 1):

For the last few months I have switched to just using the developer tools included with IE8.  It lets you change the document rendering mode on the fly (Quirks, IE7, IE8) as well as the browser mode (IE7, IE8, IE8 Compatibility).  Combined with Virtual PC for any additional browsers that may need to be tested it's a pretty solid setup that is nice and convenient.

Comment: Even though it does have these modes, IE8 does not completely replicate the behavior of IE7. Even though I've switched to IE7 mode, I can still see differences between it and IE7.

Answer (score 0):

The application [MultipleIE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE) that lets you run IE 3, 4, 5, 5.5 and 6 at the same time.

And then you can run [IE7 in standalone mode](http://tredosoft.com/IE7_standalone).