# Need a good Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8 standalone

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-internet-explorer-6-internet-explorer-7-and-internet-explorer-8-on-the)

I need recommendations on a good Internet Explorer standalone for Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8.

I tried using [Tredosoft's Internet Explorer 7 standalone](http://tredosoft.com/IE7_standalone) and MultiIE for Internet Explorer 6, but select elements were being blocked as pop-ups, even when the pop-up blocker was turned off, in all Internet Explorer browsers (6,7,8).

I also tried the Internet Explorer Collection from Edskes, but Internet Explorer 6 and Internet Explorer 7 refuse to let me type in a text box.

If someone can provide me with either a solution or an alternative that'd be brilliant.

Also, I'm using [VMware Fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Fusion) to run Windows XP on my Mac.

Comment: You'll first have to tell some of us what an "IE standalone" is.

Comment: I suspect he means an IE that isn't tied into Windows.

Comment: OK, the end result of what I'm trying to do is be able to run IE6, IE7 and IE8 on the same installation of Windows and have them behave as they normally would.

I can't use browser shots as I need to be able to test functionality, not just layout.

I think I might try the Xenocode ones for the short term, but I'm looking for something that I can run locally.

Comment: I won't be going for the Microsoft option as I'm hoping for something that continues to work and that I don't have to deal with every three months. It sounds like far too much of an issue. I'm going to look into using multiple snapshots or multiple virtual machines unless someone has a better option.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could try [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

**Update**
In 2015 this is now the wrong answer to this question. See the accepted answer of the duplicate question linked above for a better solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/574465/70795)

Comment: This has worked very well for me.  Easily open a URL in IE 5.5, 6, 7, 8 all with one click.

Comment: This is the coolest thing ever. Where is the buzz?

Comment: IETester is a great little app but be warned it isn't a true representation of the various versions of IE.

Comment: I just tried this. It's completely off for IE 6, & 7.

Comment: No way to turn off Flash in IETester :(

Comment: @asnyder i also just tried this. it is not off for ie6 or 7

Comment: It has always given me varied results - in some instances it has definitely NOT given the same results of the actual browsers...

Comment: Stupid parent company software only works in IE8. IE9's IE8 development mode doesn't work, IETester doesn't work, FF/etc doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think testing natively is the best

Comment: The compatibility VM's are the only true way to test IE8 as @rifferte says in their answer below.

Comment: @Hades if I was answering this today I would agree with you. I have also found Browserstack useful recently.

Answer (score 36):

Have you tried the compatibility virtual machines? They are from MS and free. I have used them for IE 6 testing.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

VM's are available for 6,7, and 8 in Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts...great link though!

Comment: Bear in mind that these images expire after a few months (all at the same time, so if you download it a day before it expires then you will only have its use for a day).  They also require the free MS Virtual PC 2007.  New ones are typically released within a week or two of the old ones expiring (not immediately, which is annoying) and are valid for about 3 months.

Comment: Microsoft organized all their browser VMs in one place now, available here: http://www.modern.ie/en-US/virtualization-tools#downloads

Answer (score 12):

If you need a way to test your app on the different IE-versions, you can **download and install** **Microsoft Virtual PC**: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=04d26402-3199-48a3-afa2-2dc0b40a73b6

...and **download VHD-files** with Windows installations with the different browsers included:
http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en

Answer (score 5):

Spoon provides a good list of virtualized browsers, including IE 6, 7 and 8.

http://spoon.net/browsers/

Comment: I have noticed odd behaviour previously with this method - rendering engines not behaving like the original counterparts.

Comment: Spoon WAS brilliant... Until Microsoft pulled the plug on it.
http://www.virtualizationpractice.com/blog/?p=8204

Comment: You can get IE6,7,8,9 from Spoon.net (March 2012, UK) - but only for 2 minutes use every 24 hours unless you pay US$8/month. Not a terrible price for a professional tool, but the idea of *anyone* receiving money in exchange for IE6 makes me feel ill... Also I don't know of any way to make it work with my-debugbar.com's IE debug bar.

Answer (score 2):

You're out of luck if you're trying to run them all reliably in one VM. There are several products out there, but none are perfect (they work mostly through DLL hacks).

My recommendation would be to create multiple VMs in VMware and install a different version of Internet Explorer on each. That way you get the true, full experience.

Comment: I can create multiple snapshots but where do I get the IE installers?

Comment: @dougoftheabaci http://browsers.evolt.org/

Comment: Checking if this is true :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859010

Answer (score 1):

Test in IE 6, 7, 8 and about 50 other browsers on multiple platforms for free, with no downloads or virtual machines required: http://browsershots.org/

Comment: its quite rare that screenshots alone will provide the kind of insight required for a javascript heavy app.

Comment: @seengee: I don't think the OP even mentioned JS...

Comment: These tests are often misconfigured, you can only check, that it works/not works for the whole page. It is impossible to test multiple times, because 1 page shots takes hours to complete.

Comment: Still a handy service if you don't have time to meticulously fire up 30 different VMs, you can at least give it a look over and find problem areas.

Answer (score 1):

Clone your VMWare virtual machine, and selectively upgrade the clones.

Answer (score 1):

I love this one, best one I've used so far:

http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE

Comment: Last updated in 2006 ...

Comment: The problem with MultipleIE is that it doesn't work on Win 64bit (Vista/7/8). I used it while on XP and it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xenocode.com/

I started looking at this the other day.  It seemed to work ok in my very limited testing.

Comment: always been a bit uncertain about this, anyone had any experience with it?

Comment: On one hand it's the quickest testing method, and it can be launched from any browser almost. At the same time....
 
I have noticed odd behaviour previously with this method - rendering engines not behaving like the original counterparts.

Also, there is also the privacy issue of how much of your data the company providing the service can see.

Comment: Has now become Spoon, which was good, but now doesn't support IE.

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes I've used the browsers archive at http://browsers.evolt.org/ . The Internet Explorer 6 standalone version work on Windows XP; it does't work on Windows Vista.

Comment: What is the specific problem with this answer? I hate it when people downvote and don't comment. Do the browsers at that link not work? Are they full of malware? Or are they fine, and Bo just wrote his original answer unclearly? I wish people would respect the community and share what they know...

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason, but I just went to this site as I'm looking for standalones myself, and they appear to only have IE6, which means this wouldn't answer the question asked. (But then again, the tredosoft link above appears to have the same problem, so who knows.)