# IE Emulator - simulate IE 6 in an OS with IE8 installed

Tags: internet-explorer, emulation

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Running IE6, IE7, and IE8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine)
>   [Need a good IE6,7,8 standalone.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065989/need-a-good-ie6-7-8-standalone)

Hi guyz,

I have IE 8 on my desktop. But I need to test my asp.net website on IE6 and a couple of other versions of IE. Can you tell me if there is a way to simulate IE 6 without actually installing it(I dont have the permission to install previous versions of IE).

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065989/need-a-good-ie6-7-8-standalone & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine

Comment: Open IE8, pretend everything is broken and slow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Microsoft offers [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) for this purpose; these are canned VMs offering Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8, running under virtual copies of Windows XP or Vista.

The VPC images are intended for use in Virtual PC and can also be made to work in VirtualBox or VMware Workstation (since each of those can import VPC images).

This assumes that you have permission to run virtualization software.

Comment: Does Windows Virtual PC run install on XP?

Comment: According to http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/virtual-pc-2007.aspx, it runs on XP Pro (not sure about Home).  If Virtual PC won't work, I know that VirtualBox (which is free) and VMware Workstation will.

Comment: I have installed VMWare. Now can I just point the vmware to the appropriate VPC images?

Answer (score 10):

I'm using this one [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)

Answer (score 4):

You have some options to accomplish that:

1. **Use [browsershots.org](http://www.browsershots.org)**. This will however only provide static renderings, so the behavior of the website cannot be observed.
2. **Use a [standalone IE6](http://browsers.evolt.org/?ie/win32/standalone)**. I haven't tried one personally, but it is said to have some quirks. Might work well.
3. **Install a windows xp into a virtual machine**. This will give you 100% vanilla IE6, and leave your system clean. To keep the virtual disk small, you may consider installing some "tiny"-xp modification, or create one yourself with [nlite](http://www.nliteos.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommends using a virtual machine.

Standalone versions of IE 6 are not a good idea to use. they sometimes use dlls of IE 8 so you could have the JavaScript engine of ie8 inside of a "standalone" IE 6. I read this somewhere on a Microsoft page but I forgot the link.

One cool tool I've found is made by Microsoft called [superpreview](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en). It allows you to view your pages side by side or on top of each other semi-transparently. The opaque view is cool since you can spot rendering inconsistencies right away.

Comment: Which version of IE6? Because I had a standalone of IE6 on two different machine, with slightly different sub-versions, and they rendered things differently!

Answer (score 0):

One of them http://browsershots.org/ and only a screen shot not a realy live view.

Answer (score 0):

You could

- a) grab a standalone version of IE6 (
  google for one.. tredosoft had some )
- b) use a virtual machine such as
  VirtualBox and create a new virtual
  partition on HD + new OS and get an
  OS that runs IE6 natively