# IE6 and IE7 Standalone: What do they render differently?

Tags: windows, rendering, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

It's common knowledge on SO (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065989/need-a-good-ie6-7-8-standalone)) that to run IE6 and IE7 you need a Windows box (or virtual box) with only those apps installed. I doubt this is true (they are the real versions, I think).

The two browsers I'm interested in are:

1. Standalone IE6 from [the MultipleIEs install](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE)
2. [Standalone IE7 also from Tredosoft](http://ie7-standalone.en.softonic.com/) (but published elsewhere)

These two plus a "real" install of IE8 give you three IE versions in one Windows install.

We all know that "You're out of luck if you're trying to run them all reliably in one VM," but **can someone please show me JS, CSS, or HTML (or a plugin, etc.) that does not work on the standalone versions as it should?**

**Downvoters:** I'm fixing the question so that it's less aggressive, but since there are no comments I don't know what you don't like about this question. Also: I have ALL the test cases set up (IE6, IE7 and IE8, as well as the standalone versions) so if anybody has any code they want me to test, I can do that.

Comment: I don't use IE7 standalone anymore, since IE8's developer tools allow simple switching of the rendering engine.

Comment: @Boldewyn, so you've never found any inconsistencies between IE8 dev tools and IE7 for real?

Comment: http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/IETester-Download-101019.html - IE Tester - 5.5, 6, 7, 8, 9. They all work the code as they should. visual rendering *slightly off - but ya Multiple IE don't work on windows 7 for me.

Comment: Even I saw problems with IETester.

Comment: In this day and age, unless you really really need to support IE6, and are being actively paid to do so, should vote with your feet, and give it a good kick.

Comment: @danp, obviously I am being "actively paid" to support IE6, otherwise I'd just do IE8 and latest versions :)

Comment: @yar: In the improbable case (it was just once since IE8 was published) that a client with native IE7 sees something different than I, I still have my VirtualPC-IE7 around to double-check. But, no, in all other cases I'm fine with the dev tools.

Comment: @Glycerine, yeah, the idea would be to have an XP in a VirtualBox. Since you'd need that anyway to test various IEs.

Comment: By the way: I'm no downvoter, the question is legal to ask. In fact I'm curious, too, about the answers since I once f***ed up my IE installation with IE5.5, IE6 and IE7 in parallel.

Comment: @yar @Boldewyn http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx

Comment: @Typeoneerror, yeah, I kind of suspected that. The idea of a "compatibility mode" just sounds like it'll have problems :)... but in my experience, the standalones NEVER fail (which is what I'm trying to disprove here, if possible). Did you ever think of putting some underscores in your name?

Answer (score 1):

Is IE-Tester a tool you can use?  I use it daily in my work.

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage