# i have IE8 but some of my users have ie6

Tags: cross-browser

how is the best way to be able to simulate ie6 in my machine to see what user experience these users get.

do i have to install ie6 or is there some other way to simulate it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a virtual machine with XP and IE6.  Microsoft has [downloads](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) that make it easy to do this for various OS/browser combinations.

Comment: yup VHD's are the way to go. All the tools like ietester etc are not a good real test.

Comment: If you're running Windows 7 you can run IE6 and IE7 on your desktop, when the're actually running in the virtual pc. It's a really cool feature. And you don't have to install those virtual pc images from MS (they expire every now and then) It's a really cool feature.

Answer (score 6):

IE Tester: http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: +1. This tool is invaluable and saves me from having to install VMs or muck about with multiple copies of IE.

Comment: I will make a note of this one. +1

Comment: I have already seen elements that look different on IE Tester's IE6 and native IE6 installed on a VM.

Answer (score 2):

You can also install multiple ie by tredosoft: http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) and use an image with IE6 that you can download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en).

Microsoft is developing a tool called [SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx) to view different browser renderings in the same program, that seems to be nearing the final release. There is a beta that you can download, but it only supports IE8 and IE8 in compatibility mode so far.

Comment: I agree, Microsoft's Virtual PC IE6 image is the best option

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with static rendering, than [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) might be a good idea.

If not, I'd suggest to set up an old xp in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a standalone version of IE6 from here: http://browsers.evolt.org/?ie/win32/standalone

It's not perfect, but it lets you run IE6 alongside whatever browser you have installed, without the two interfering with each other too much.

Comment: The standalone versions have issues.

Comment: @David: You're right, but it gets you a 99% solution in two minutes flat.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install IE6 if you want a decent test.

See [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use a VM, as tvanfosson says.
Another good option if your able to deploy your site on to the internet is to use [browserpool](http://browserpool.de/kc/wob/portal.jsp?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Browserlab](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/browserlab/) is also a handy (and quick compared to browsershots et. al) tool to get snapshots of what your site looks like in various browsers. Obviously not as good as actually installing IE... but useful nonetheless