# Test jQuery & JavaScript on IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to test my web app on IE6. Obviously I have IE8 installed on my machine, I've tought about using a Virtual Machine, are there any other options?.

I wan't to make sure my jQuery and JavaScript code functions properly....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other options are:

- Use a non-virtual machine (inefficient)
- Use one of the hacks to install multiple versions of IE side-by-side (unreliable, especially when it comes to JS testing).

A virtual machine is the right way to go.

Comment: only answer I see that right +1. IE side by side cant really verify that its giving true 100% browser rendering to that version.

Comment: If you are looking to test IE versions, you should really check out https://github.com/xdissent/ievms.  It gives you a simple path to having each ie version starting at 6.

Answer (score 3):

Check out IETester:

http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be: use [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). Also see this topic for more suggestions: [Internet Explorer 6 and Internet Explorer 7 on same computer for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669124/ie-6-and-ie-7-on-same-computer-for-debugging)

Comment: Correction: IE5.5/IE6 isn't good with Javascript. Apart from that it works very well. It has the engine as originally used in real IE browsers.

Comment: @hminaya- it is good for testing purposes, but as for JS the only 100% accurate way would be using a VM, IEtester does work but I have heard of the different errors it brings when it comes to JS.ex: popups

Answer (score 1):

you could use [IE tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

Answer (score 0):

[IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) allows you to try IEs 5.5, 6, 7, and 8 in one program, with very few limitations.

Answer (score 0):

[IE Collection](http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm) is another option for you.  I have only been using it for about a week, and the IE6 menu interface is a bit buggy, but so far JavaScript and CSS behave consistently with my other PC which has IE6 on it.  It will let you install several older (pre-6.0) versions as well.