# Have a range of IE builds on test machine

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, web-applications

I currently have a testing environment for web apps on a virtual machine.

The problem - i would like to keep IE 6 for testing and also have access to newer versions of IE as well.

How can i do this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running IE6, IE7, and IE8 on the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Virtual PC and a couple XP images with IE6 and IE7 that Microsoft supplies at:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en

I also install other versions of firefox and opera on those virtual images as well. The current images expire on July 1st, but they will likely replenish those with other images in the future. (Hopefully!)

Comment: Also very interesting - in relation to Adrian Facius post will the IETester provide the same results im looking for or is your method more reliable?

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. I'm sure someone else might be able to answer that more accurately than I can. Though I am aware of IE Tester and http://browsershots.org/ and the like, being somewhat anal, I prefer to use the actual browsers to test and debug any pages as it diminishes a lot of uncertainty for me, particularly with IE. :)

Comment: @Dan Having different virtual machines each whit it's own version of IE it's clearly more reliable. IETester has a few known limitations, check them on the webpage. If these limitations are not a problem for you then IETester would be a much simpler solution, otherwise just use the virtual machines.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback this is obviously something i'm going to have to look into a bit more before i make a decision. Cheers again.

Comment: THe easy way to get all the IE VMs is to use the script at https://github.com/xdissent/ievms, which will download them and set them all up.

Answer (score 1):

On the same machine it's a little harder to do. You could try to use something like [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). Other solution would be simply to have a testing environment for each version of IE.

Comment: Perfect.. i was dreading the thought of having a bazillion different virtual machines its just too much overkill. This however is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Don't use IETester; it won't give you reliable results and you still have to have a bazillion virtual machines.