# Does anyone know of an IE7 emulator?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, emulation

I'm on Mac running parallels with windows XP and IE8 installed. The options I find either don't work with my version of Firefox or dont install correctly on the windows side. Do you know of any emulators for internet explorer?

What I'm looking for is to emulate websites in ie7 and ie6 to check. I know of IE=EmulateIE7 but will that force all users in IE8 to view in IE7? I'd rather fix my code than force someone to view in a different mode...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running IE6, IE7, and IE8 on the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx) in Expression Blend can do that. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine/663781#663781).

Alternatively, you can create another Windows XP image with just IE6 and run it using Parallels.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried installing SuperPreview and i kept getting an unexpected close when it tried to install..of course that's probably on my virtual XP side and not the software's fault...

Comment: I got superpreview to work on another computer. Thanks, didn't even think of creating another xp image...

Answer (score 3):

[IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)  is the way to go. IE 5.5, 6, 7, 8 in one package.

Answer (score 2):

Try using one of Microsoft's VirtualPC images for IE7. They give them away for free but they expire every couple of months.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

You can download VirtualPC in Windows. It will probably run really slow in Parallels but you could also use Boot Camp and then run VirtualPC.

Answer (score 1):

http://spoon.net/browsers/ is very handy too.

Answer (score 0):

VPC is really the way to go, get the images from [microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 0):

If you're already running Parallels, I'd suggest just using another VM for XP + IE7. It's the cleanest solution and provides the most reliable IE7 'emulation'.