# can we install and use ie6 & ie7 at the sametime?

Tags: browser

i have ie6 installed on my winxp system..can i install ie7 separately and use both of them at the same...if it possible advise me..

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Expression Web Super Preview, which is a free download from Microsoft. This is a great and easy way to check your pages in several versions of IE.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en

Comment: As of April 2011, that page appears gone. They do have the product at [SuperPreview](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/SuperPreview_Overview.aspx), although it looks commercial only.

Comment: There is a beta of a new version of SuperPreview, which will also include non-ie and non-windows previews, i.e. Safari, Chrome, Firefox on Windows and Mac. It is only packaged with Expression Web though - sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Search for "multiple IE" on Google: http://www.google.de/search?q=multiple+ie

There are ways to install several versions of IE on your computer, there also is freeware to accomplish this, e.g. "IETester".

(a search on SO would've led you here: [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine))