# Testing the website accross multiple IE versions

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463)

I am testing my website on different versions of Internet Explorer. What is the best tool to perform the test on the same machine?

I came across a tool called [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). Is this tool recommended?

How do you typically perform this type of test?

Note: I have tried http://spoon.net/browsers/. It looks very promising.

Comment: make it work on IE8 and then stop caring.

Comment: @Jason, and forget about the rest? I am with you on IE is a POS, especially pre-IE8. However, the real world needs to accommodate to all valid platforms. Especially those damned government employees :)

Comment: i develop in firefox (for firebug purposes), check in chrome, and when i'm done, make sure it looks ok/functions mostly correctly in IE8. If I'm feeling particularly ambitious, I'll make sure it works in IE7. past that, I don't care. Google, YouTube, and many other big-name sites have dropped support for IE6 and below, so there's no reason you should support them either.

Comment: I follow the exact same process, but I can't exclude IE6/7. I wish and can't wait till I can. Spend more time fixing IE6 then building the damn site to begin with.

Comment: Possible duplicate? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921205/how-can-i-test-my-webpage-in-different-ie-versions
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine

Answer (score 1):

I personally run VM's for all the different environments/browsers. However I recently ran across spoon.net, which allows you to load applications with no install. They have all browsers that I would care to test in.

http://www.spoon.net/Browsers/

Comment: I certainly like VM's as well. The only viable way to do web development testing in Linux.

Comment: I have tried spoon. It looks very promising.