# Test Website with IE7

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, testing, windows-7, internet-explorer-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-internet-explorer-6-internet-explorer-7-and-internet-explorer-8-on-the)

I need to test a website with IE7.

Does anyone know if there was a way of doing this in windows7 without setting up a VM with XP+SP2 on it?

Comment: Duplicate of at least 5 other questions.

Comment: Apologies, though I'm not surprised there are so many duplicates - they don't show up in the similar questions when you ask the question - I ALWAYS check!

Comment: That could be because your question title doesn't really reflect your question, and your question body is unusually terse.

Comment: better shoot me for insubordination then...I think my question is very specific and efficient. how would you ask this question... maybe I should put the implied 'How can I' at the beginning?.. it is a simple question after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Expression Web SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx) is Microsoft's own tool for this.

Answer (score 4):

I like [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) a lot. Works pretty good and no need to have the old versions installed. It runs on 7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Spoon Browser Sandbox](http://spoon.net/browsers/).

Comment: Using this one as it supports more browsers and doesn't need install.

Comment: Didn't know about this one. Looks very competent.

Comment: What are people's experience with this tool? How reliable is it?

Comment: So far it has never let me down. It requires installing a plugin, but it supports a lot of browsers.

Comment: after using it for a while, i didn't like it, sorry (still upvote thou as it could be useful in the future).