# Testing on IE7, 6

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I want to test my site on IE7 and 6, but where can I download them? I checked the Microsoft site but I cannot find a download link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running IE6, IE7, and IE8 on the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine)

Comment: Simply download virtual machines from here : https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads . Check your website as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to install XP cleanly, I'd recommend creating a new virtual machine using something like VirtualPC or VirtualBox, and loading XP onto it, leaving IE6. Save this image out, then upgrade to IE7. Now you'll have to VHDs, one with IE6, and one with IE7.

As far as I know, you can't have more than one version installed on a machine, so you wouldn't be able to use the three versions side-by-side on your real machine anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ietester http://ietester.com/