# How to debug with an older version of Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

I am using windows 7 with Internet Explorer 8 for browsing and Visual Studio 2008 as the SDK. Since the client's standard is Internet Explorer 6, I need to make sure the look and feel is consistent for older versions. Compatibility mode will not do, since I am trying to view a new page with an old browser, not the other way around.

What I really need is a way to use Internet Explorer 6 when I debug in Visual Studio. How to set this up?

Comment: Uninstall IE8 -> Install IE6. Sorted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running IE6, IE7, and IE8 on the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIR Microsoft has a free Virtual PC image that contains Windows XP and IE6 just for testing web applications by developers.

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) it is.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).
In order to make Visual Studio 2008 to use Internet Explorer 6 as a default browser you have to perform these actions:

1. Right click on aspx file
2. Click on Browse With...
3. Add
4. Specify path to `IETester.exe`
5. Add command line parameter `-IE6` to path. For example: `"C:\Program Files\Core Services\IETester\IETester.exe" -IE6`
6. Click OK
7. Visual Studio says `File name does not exist, is invalid, or contains parameters that cannot be validated. Do you want to change your entry?`. Click No.
8. Click Browse
9. Your application is opened in IETester in Internet Explorer 6 mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx) in Windows 7, or you can use a [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and install Windows XP with IE 6 in it. Or you can use Microsoft Virtual PC and download an image of [Windows XP with IE6](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en) from Microsoft

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to mess around with virtual machines (although that's my recommendation), there are two more options:

1. [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)
2. [MultipleIEs](http://multipleies.en.softonic.com/)

I haven't tried using them directly with VS 2008, but you might have luck with them.