# Multiple Internet Explorer version browser testing (Internet Explorer 6-8)?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

One of the best applications I've ever had the privelege of using was Tredosoft's [MultipleIE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE) application.

However, now that I'm using Windows 7, and that application was never ported to Windows 7, there does not appear to be a similar installable product available for testing pages in multiple versions of Internet Explorer.

Then along came [Spoon](http://www.spoon.net/Browsers/).

However, they've pulled their Internet Explorer sandbox emulator due to a Microsoft [cease and desist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cease_and_desist) (WTF?)

So how do I test my web page designs in Internet Explorer 7 (I have Internet Explorer 8 installed), preferably via localhost?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running IE6, IE7, and IE8 on the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine)

Comment: Spoon seems back in the game (February 2014) with IE browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try http://www.brothersoft.com/ietester-153799.html

Comment: Thanks Kishan, do you know if I can test from localhost with that app?

Comment: you will find web browsers inside those, so simply type localhost urls.it will run perfectly...

Comment: SWEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEET! Thanks Kishan (et al) :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out Microsoft Expression Web 4's SuperPreview: http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx

It should let you test locally IE6-9, including compatibility modes. It also supports other browsers you might have installed locally and has a beta for remote browsers.