# Internet explorer testing

Tags: internet-explorer, testing

Does anyone know any tools I can use to view my site in different browsers for styling purposes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running IE6, IE7, and IE8 on the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-on-the-same-machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Expression Web SuperPreview](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/dd565874.aspx)
- [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)
- [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/)