# Crossbrowser platform testing

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, cross-platform

I am running some tests for extjs library that we are using in our development for ie8  on 2 platforms win xp and win 7.

I am noticing that  ie8 on win xp the grid tables are not correctly aligned.
But IE8 on win7 looks perfect.

What is the best way to apply cross browser/cross platform fixes?

Do i apply browser specific css or ie selection statements fixes?
any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-internet-explorer-6-internet-explorer-7-and-internet-explorer-8-on-the)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would do is run the developer tools (F12) in both cases and make sure that Browser Mode and Document Mode is the same in both cases. If they are set to IE8 mode it the page should render the same way.