# how to install multiple version internet explore 6 & 7 & 8

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

I am new web developer and I have IE 9 in my PC.
I want install multiple version IE in my PC but I don't know about it.
I search in this site and find this "Try http://www.brothersoft.com/ietester-153799.html" but when see this site understand I can install IE Version 3-6 but I don't know how to install IE version 7 & 8 in my PC????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-internet-explorer-6-internet-explorer-7-and-internet-explorer-8-on-the)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to install multiple versions because IE has backwards compatability. Just press F12 to open the developer console, and from there you can choose how do you want the website to render like, IE-7 - IE-9

[image]

This does not support IE6 and below, but if a person is still using that they do not want to live in the real world so I suggest just pushing them away by not supporting those browsers...

Comment: Beyond using the developer tools' emulation, http://modern.ie offers free VMs for IE versions. You should avoid hacks like "IETester" as they can introduce bugs that don't exist in the real browser version.