# Install different versions of IE in same machine

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, browser

How to install different versions of `IE`, without using Virtual PCs.

Is there any simulators ... ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-internet-explorer-6-internet-explorer-7-and-internet-explorer-8-on-the)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to use VMs. Even if that's not the answer you want to hear, that *is* the answer.

Running (some of) them on the same machine is just about possible, but you shouldn't do it, because they rely on external components, which you also can't have multiple versions of, so yes, you'll end up with (for example) IE6 running alongside other versions, but it will not be the same as the IE6 you started with. In particular, the activeX components are suceptible to this, so if your site uses any `filter` styles for example, you may get unexpected side effects.

The only reason you'd want multiple versions of IE is for testing purposes, but the above should be enough to prove that even if you do achieve it, it won't give you valid tests.

So we go back to the original point, which is to use a VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IETester (http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) This works quite nicely for testing multiple versions of IE.